# SQL: ORDER BY with 2 criteria not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

In my work I have 2 tables:

- Airports(serial_number, name, maker, model_name (which is a foreign key to the next table), op_start_date, op_end date
- Models (name, number_rows, is_narrow, is_wide)

With them I have to make a table with the information for each airplane of their name, maker, model, and if they are wide-body or narrow-body. Adiotionally, I am supposed to order the list by their maker and their model.

The code I tried is below

```
SELECT maker, Airplanes.name, model_name, is_narrow, is_wide
FROM Airplanes 
   JOIN Models ON model_name=Models.name
ORDER BY maker, model_name;
```

However the table obtained was this one:

Link to the image:

[image]

As you can see, it's ordered by maker, but not model. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you ran with two columns in `Order by`. I don't think it is possible. Can you add the sample data I don't think it can be replicated

Comment: @Prdp I tried running 2 other columns with the same data and it ordered them correctly. Firstly the column mentioned first, and inside those (if they have the same value) it orders them by the second column

Comment: What database are you working with (including version)?

Comment: I am working with my own database, and using SQL Server 13.0.1722.
I already found the solution provided on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

This could occur if you had invisible characters in the maker.

Try running:

```
SELECT a.maker, count(*)
FROM Airplanes a
GROUP BY a.maker
ORDER BY a.maker;
```

See if the "same" value for `maker` turns up more than once.

Comment: It does have different value, particularly the one that wasn't ordered correctly.

How can I correct it?

Comment: @MasterExcrement . . . You need to fix the value.  I don't know why they are different or what the correct values should be.  `UPDATE` comes to mind as a solution for fixing the data.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick! 
Don't know what was that "invisible character", but it's working now! Thanks!